# Artisan (Laravel) can't create migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I had problems running the php artisan migrate command.

When I type:

```
php artisan make:migration create_test_table
```

I get:

```
 Process finished with exit code 255 at 22:12:19.
 Execution time: 492 ms.
```

However, these worked without any error:

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan migrate:reset
```

I'm use OS X 10.11.6, PHPStorm latest version, MAMP (MySQL) in localhost.
I tried to manually delete the table and make `composer dump-autoload`, but I got the same result.

Any idea?

PS:

```
> php artisan migrate:status
+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Ran? | Migration                                      |
+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Y    | 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table           |
| Y    | 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table |
| Y    | 2016_08_7_213420_create_messages_table         |
+------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on `database/migrations` directory?

Comment: are you mean it? [link](http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/2016/08/08/0006/1753/427737/37/2473d1b057.png)

Comment: Yes. Permissions look correct. What is the output of `php artisan migrate:status`?

Comment: linuxartisan, i'm add `migrate:status` to question

Comment: Try read this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/creating-triggers-from-migration?page=1